# react-native-fs library is not moving or copying files - weird results

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-fs

```
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^4.13.0 => 4.13.0
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3
    react-native-windows: Not Found
    react-native-fs: ^2.16.6
    react-native-image-picker: ^2.3.4
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
    Visual Studio: 15.3.26730.12 (Visual Studio Community 2017)
```

I've been trying to implement a button that opens the camera, takes a picture and saves it to pictures folder.

For this I'm using:

- [react-native-image-picker](https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-image-picker/) to take the picture
- [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to move the picture to a filename of my choosing

It's the latter that's giving me a headache.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
<Buttons.Camera containerStyle={{marginBottom:5}}
  onPress={() => {
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, async (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        // ToDo cancelled
        console.log('Cancellen');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('Camera Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
        const ext = response.fileName?.split('.').pop();
        let newPath = `${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}/${options.storageOptions.path}/avatar.${ext}`;
        const result = await RNFS.moveFile(response.path, newPath);
        this.setState({
          avatarPath: newPath,
        });
      }
    });
  }} />
```

A breakpoint is hit on `const result = await RNFS.moveFile(response.path, newPath);`. I can confirm that the image does exist in my galary and that `newPath` and  `response.path` are both valid.
When I try to move the file (rename, in fact) I notice that there's no image at `newPath` and the original image at `response.path` appears to be corrupted and can't be opened anymore.

According to the docs, `result` should be `true`, but in my case it is `undefined`.
The same happens when I use `RNFS.exists(newPath)`. The promise resolves but the result is `undefined`. No errors are thrown.

Any ideas?